# How to write conditional jade when there is two different design for a layout?

Tags: css, pug, harp

I am building a website on harp.js. 
I have a layout.jade file which includes _header.jade which is written like

```
   != partial("_header")
   != yield
   != partial("_footer")
```

Now, there is a change in my design. I do not want all the header look same. If I want different header for the website, how should I put condition to jade file?

Answer (score 0):

pass some variable like `layout` into your template then you can use a simple condition in the template.

```
if layout === '1'
  != partial("_hedaer1")
else if layout === '2'
  != partial("_header2")
```

otherwise you could render the content and the layout independent from each other

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did it with second one.